# /dev/ttyACM busy for the first 15 seconds after plugging

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, tty

I have two USB devices which appear as /dev/ttyACMn (a barcode reader and a motor controller). For each of them, when I try to open them in the first 15 seconds after plugging in, I get a "device or resource busy" error. After more than 15 seconds, they open fine. Do you have any idea what's causing it?

I tried using lsof to check if a process is using the device, but it finds no such process (it finds my process after I manage to connect to the device).

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 3.13.0 64-bit, but I have seen this behavior in earlier Ubuntu versions too.

Thank you very much,

Noam

Comment: Do you have a package called brltty installed?  That has sometimes caused conflicts.

Comment: I had brltty installed, but removing it had no effect. It was ModemManager to blame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/). It scans serial interfaces on startup to see, if they belong to a modem.

Comment: Indeed - that was the problem. Thanks a lot!